# How to output a voltage proportional to the speed of a DC motor?

Tags: dc-motor, measurement, speed

Take a DC motor, as the one in the picture below:

[image: DC motor picture]

I need some kind of analogic signal (preferably proportional to the speed of the motor) that can be used in a control loop.

What are two simple ways of achieving this? (One would be enough as well). If you have experience with some specific parts, please do supply the part number too.

I thought about using a hall effect sensor, but that would give me a digital signal and I wouldn't know how to filter it properly....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would use an analog tachometer. These devices are a precision (DC) dynamo whose output voltage is a linear function of speed.

[image]

*Figure 1. An analog tachometer mounted on the rear of the motor.*

You can also purchase separate tachometers which could be mounted somewhere else on the drive train.

Comment: You might not like the price, but that's another matter...

Comment: @BrianDrummond yeah.. that's a good idea, although I was thinking of something cheaper... Home made is fine too, I don't need exceptional precision..

Answer (score 3):

If you are using PWM to control motor speed you can analyse back EMF from motor at the end of each pulse. That will give you proportional value to the speed.

To simplyfy that, you can basically measure average voltage from the motor after end of pulse and before next one.

Easy and cheap method. Fast enough to control speed, although with higher error margin than for example tacho.

Comment: I didn't think about that! Do you have any resources you'd suggest for applying this method?

Comment: There is plenty around but try for example that: https://www.precisionmicrodrives.com/application-notes/ab-021-measuring-rpm-from-back-emf